# Multilingual citation lists with apacite

Tags: bibliographies, languages, citing, apa-style

I am writing a paper for university and i need to use german and english captions in the bibliography list. If the source is in english then the entry must be also in english, if it's in german it must be in german.
Can anybody help me. I am using apacite and bibtex since i have to cite according to APA.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you mean by captions? A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) might help.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use the package `biblatex`with the `style=apa` option, then you can use the hyphenation data field for english and german.